# JQuery how to apply on list of selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newby with Jquery and I'm trying to find out how to apply on a list of selectors. Sometimes I need to be able to differentiate c1,c2 and c3. For others I'd like to apply to the three something

```
$c1 = $div.find('#widget-row-c').sortedList();
$c2 = $div.find('#widget-col-c').sortedList();
$c2 = $div.find('#widget-filter-c').sortedList();
$containers = ?  // as $c1 + $c2 + $c3

$c1.doSomethingForC1();  // only for c1
$containers.doSomethingForC1C2C3();  // for all three
```

How it's possible to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$containers = $c1.add($c2).add($c3);`.

Answer (score 4):

Just separate your selectors with commas

```
var containers = $('#widget-row-c, #widget-col-c, #widget-filter-c');
```

Comment: Also, if you still want to select them seperately as above, you can merge the results: `jQuery.merge(jQuery.merge($c1, $c2), $c3)`

Comment: Thanks :-), I had a class in the div (".sortedList") but using this didn't work.

Comment: @iterion, merge no. it's looking as after that $c1.doSomething() goes on all c1,c2,c3

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right: `jQuery.merge(jQuery.merge(jQuery.merge([],$c1), $c2), $c3)` The above merged down to the original array $c1, doesn't look pretty though...

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using both `id` and `class` selectors for this. If all elements have, say, a `widget-container` class you could do:

```
$c1 = $div.find('#widget-row-c').sortedList();
$c2 = $div.find('#widget-col-c').sortedList();
$c3 = $div.find('#widget-filter-c').sortedList();
$containers = $('.widget-container');

$c1.doSomethingForC1();  // only for c1
$containers.doSomethingForC1C2C3();  // for all three
```

Basically, if you know you're going to want to select a single thing, grab it by `Id`. Otherwise, grab all of the same kind by selecting by `class`